# Accuracy of face detection with haarcascade

Tags: opencv, face-detection

Recently I am confused by some strange things occur when I do face detection with "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml"

Say when detecting my face in the video captured by web camera, although neither my face nor the camera moves, the coordinates and size of face returned would change a little. Why is this going to happen? Is there a way to improve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How much is a little?  As long as the coordinates and size values for the detected face do not jump around wildly, you might be able to smooth things out with a low-pass filter (i.e. a running average).

I don't know what language you are using, but in Python, it would look something like this:

```
filterSize = 3
m = []

while True:
   x, y, sizex, sizey = <getThisFramesFaceParams()> ## Your function here
   m.append([x,y,sizex,sizey])
   if len(m) > filterSize:
      m.pop

   x, y, sizex, sizey = 0, 0, 0, 0
   for i in m:
      x += i[0]
      y += i[1] 
      sizex += i[2] 
      sizey += i[3]   

   # less variation in these values:
   x /= len(m)
   y /= len(m)
   sizeX /= len(m)
   sizeY /= len(m)
```

The bigger you make filterSize, the more you will suppress noise/variation (so less random change in values).  However, as that value gets bigger, you will also notice more lag.  For instance, when you move your face, you might find that the "detected" location of your face lags behind the current location of your face.  This is a trade-off you need to make depending on the amount of noise you are experiencing and the required speed of your application.